# Ground-up resources for building personal information security

Tags: email, web-browser, antivirus

Seems appropriate to work on my (weak) personal information security. So, I'm looking for pretty ground-up resources for becoming capable of looking after my information security. Specifically, what are recommended web browsers, email providers, and virus protection services? What are the most trustworthy and secure options available to someone with relatively little experience? And what resources are there for improving those capabilities?

Comment: Hello and welcome to security.SE. Product request are not allowed here for reasons you'll find in the FAQ. Take a moment to review it before further posting, please.

Comment: You can try this page for pretty extensive and simple security tips: https://fatsecurity.com/article/protect-yourself-online